# HTML jQuery smooth scroll to element and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have in my HTML something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Stackoverflow help please</title>  
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div id="scrollhere">Scroll here!</div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

And when I open page: http://example.com/index.html#scrollhere it is scrolled to this element, but I wan't to smoothly scroll, and add class for this element. How can I do this? Thanks so much.

Comment: What's your code for the scroll?

Comment: @JBux, I don't have code xD When i open this code it scrolled auto to my div

Comment: There are a lot of jQuery plugins and code snippets to do that. Do yourself a favor - google it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Stackoverflow help please</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {            
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollhere").offset().top
      }, 2000);
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="scrollhere">Scroll here!</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much, it almost, but I need not scrollTop: $("#scrollhere").offset().top **scrollhere**,  I wan't to give it from url for example http://example.com/index.html#herescroll

Answer (score 1):

The solution Andrew posted works, though only for a certain ID

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      //scrolls
      var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#'+urlHash).offset().top}, 2000); 

      //Adds the class
      $('#'+urlHash).addClass( "myClass" );
    });
</script>
```

Her you can parste any div in the URL and it will scroll to it.

Comment: You are supposed to set my answer as useful. I need dat Karma ;_;   ;) :D

Comment: xd I have only 10rep, I can't add :(